# TikZ pancake coil around a rectangle with round corners

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw a pancake coil around a rectangle with round corners?
The aim is the following:

[image: hand drawn draft]

I have no idea...

EDIT:

sorry!

I think it's better to draw it in 3d.

I'm new in Tikz.... ... my first steps to solve the problem:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[
    yshift=-130,every node/.append style={
    yslant=0.5,xslant=-1.3},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1.3
                            ]

    \draw[black,very thick,fill=gray!30] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);


    \end{scope}


    \begin{scope}[
     yshift=-100,every node/.append style={
     yslant=0.5,xslant=-1.3},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1.3
             ]

                \draw[gray!80,very thick,fill=gray!30] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);

                                \draw[black,thick] (1.5,1) rectangle (3,1.2);
                                \draw[black,thick] (1.5,2) rectangle (3,2.2);
                                \draw[black,thick] (1.5,3) rectangle (3,3.2);
                                \draw[black,thick] (1.5,4) rectangle (3,4.2);


        \end{scope}


 \begin{scope}
                    [ yshift=-220]

            %\draw[black,very thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);

\end{scope}

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Can you help my now?

data

[image: hand drawn 3D draft]

**PREFINAL**

Is it possible to use the coil in the picture , so that the connectors are in the middle? I think this looks better, then the coil 2, 4, 6... is then the coil 1,3,5... but rotate to 180 degree.

Example:
The port 2 from Coil 1 will connect to the port 2 from coil 2 and then
the port 1 from coil 2 will connect with port 1 from coil 3 ...

How can I reduce the line-distance?

[image]

Comment: You should still include some compilable code including what you can do - e.g. a rounded rectangle. If you can not do anything at all, then TikZ is not the tool for you until you have read a tutorial.

Comment: Hello, and welvome to [TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please include a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) As @hpekristiansen stated you should be able to do something ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**ALMOST (?) FINAL (?) VERSION**

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
    pancake distance/.store in=\PancakeDistance,
    pancake distance=2pt,
    pancake final node/.store in=\PancakeLastNode,
    pancake final node=finalPC,
    pancake initial pos/.store in=\PancakeIniPos,
    pancake initial pos=0.5,
    pancake final pos/.store in=\PancakeFinPos,
    pancake final pos=0.5,
    pancake/.style={rounded corners}
}
\newcommand{\DrawPancake}[4][]{
 \xdef\Pancake{($(#2)!\PancakeIniPos!(#2-|#3)$) 
  to[bend right,rounded corners=0] ($([xshift=2*\PancakeDistance,yshift=-2*\PancakeDistance]#2)!\PancakeIniPos!(#2-|#3)$)}
 \foreach \Z [evaluate={\nextZ=int(\Z+1)}] in {1,...,#4}
  {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prevZ}{int(\Z-1)}
  \coordinate (#2-\Z) at ([xshift=-\prevZ*\PancakeDistance,yshift=-\Z*\PancakeDistance]#2);
  \coordinate (#2-\nextZ) at ([xshift=-\Z*\PancakeDistance,yshift=-\nextZ*\PancakeDistance]#2);
  \coordinate (#3-\Z) at ([xshift=\Z*\PancakeDistance,yshift=\Z*\PancakeDistance]#3);
  \xdef\Pancake{\Pancake -- (#2-\Z -| #3-\Z) -- (#3-\Z) -- (#3-\Z -| #2-\nextZ) --
  (#2-\nextZ)}
  }
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextZ}{int(#4+1)}
  \xdef\Pancake{\Pancake -- ($(#2-\nextZ)!\PancakeFinPos!(#2-\nextZ -|#3)$) }
 \draw[pancake,#1] \Pancake coordinate (\PancakeLastNode);
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[
    yshift=-130,every node/.append style={
    yslant=0.5,xslant=-1.3},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1.3
                            ]

    \draw[black,very thick,fill=gray!30] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);


    \end{scope}


    \begin{scope}[
     yshift=-100,every node/.append style={
     yslant=0.5,xslant=-1.3},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1.3
             ]

     \draw[gray!80,very thick,fill=gray!30] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);

     \begin{scope}[yscale=-1,xscale=-1]
     \draw[black,thick] (-3,-1.2) coordinate(X) rectangle (-1.5,-1) coordinate(Y);
     \tikzset{pancake final node=myPC1}
     \DrawPancake{X}{Y}{4}
     \end{scope}
     \draw[black,thick] (1.5,2) coordinate(X) rectangle (3,2.2) coordinate(Y);
     \tikzset{pancake final node=myPC2}
     \DrawPancake{X}{Y}{4}
     \draw (myPC1)--(myPC2);
     \draw[black,thick] (1.5,3) coordinate (X) rectangle (3,3.2) coordinate (Y);
     \DrawPancake[dashed,blue]{X}{Y}{5}
     \draw[black,thick] (1.5,4) coordinate (X) rectangle (3,4.2) coordinate (Y);
     \tikzset{pancake distance=1.5pt}
     \DrawPancake[red]{X}{Y}{6}

        \end{scope}


 \begin{scope}
                    [ yshift=-220]

            %\draw[black,very thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);

\end{scope}

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the updates I addressed several additional requirements and also made the code a bit more Ti*k*Zy.

Comment: Hi,that looks great. How can i mirroring (at x-axis and y-axis) the coil? So, that i can connect the left coil with the middle coil. Please look my first uploaded picture. I tested the mirroring with (\begin{scope}[yscale=-1,xscale=1]\end{scope}) but the result was a horrible picture. Thanks for your work!!! data

Comment: @data Please see my update.

Comment: Sorry, but one question .... what is the easiest way to connect the start and the end of this coil with the next one?

Comment: @data Simple: just name the final coordinate somehow, store it, and then connect it with another final coordinate.

Comment: @data If the solution worked for you please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). BTW, it was not me who downvoted your answer below, but I also think that you may want to delete it.

Comment: marmot, thanks so much for the work!! Please look, i have edit the text and added a "final coil" design. Is it easy for you to edit your sourcecode?

Comment: marmot, thanks so much for the work!! Please look, i have edit the text and added a "final coil" design. Is it easy for you to edit your sourcecode? the connection from coil 2 to coil 3 and coil 4 to coil 5 ... should be in a other design or outside of the coil.

Comment: Alternative are the coils in pairs, so that the connection is to do manual. It is probable the easier way.

Comment: @data The distance between the lines is stored in `pancake distance` and the position of the initial/final contours in `pancake initial pos` and `pancake final pos`, respectively. By placing a `\tikzset` before the `\DrawPancake` command you can modify these parameters, see the red pancake contour above in which I changed the distance.

Comment: Many compliments. +1.